# Using VBA to parse text in an MS Word document

Tags: vba, parsing, ms-word

I was hoping someone could help with a MS Word Macro.

Basically, I have a MS Word document which lists out several text files and specific pages of interest in each file.

The file format is similar to:

```
textdocument1.txt              P. 6, 12 - issue1
textdocument2.txt              P. 5 - issue1
                               P. 13, 17 - issue3
textdocument3.txt              P. 10
```

I want to read each line into my Macro as a string.

Then traverse through it to identify the file name. With the file name, I can then open the file, go to the page number, and copy the data I need.

But I'm stuck at step 1, how do I capture the line into a string in an MS Word Macro?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following code should get you started:

```
Public Sub ParseLines()
    Dim singleLine As Paragraph
    Dim lineText As String

    For Each singleLine In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        lineText = singleLine.Range.Text

        '// parse the text here...

    Next singleLine
End Sub
```

I found the basic algorithm in [this article](http://visualbasic.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/vb-vba-l/vba-to-read-line-by-line-from-word-document-1822258).

Comment: This will break the document up into paragraphs.
If you want sentences do this per line (i.e. sentence) check my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

If your word document lists all the text files like this:

```
<name>{tab}<page ref>{newline}
<name>{tab}<page ref>{newline}
<name>{tab}<page ref>{newline}
```

Then all the lines are available in the [Paragraphs collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb178832.aspx). You can loop through that with a simple `For Each` loop:

```
Dim p As Paragraph

For Each p In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
  Debug.Print p.Range.Text
Next p
```

Comment: `For Each` messes up if you make changes to the object, it can get stuck on the same element for ever, I had to use an index variable.

Comment: Very true, if you alter the collection you iterate over (deleting or adding new paragraphs) then weird things will happen. Using a indexed loop might fail in this case as well.

Answer (score 2):

per line

```
Public Sub ParseDoc()

    Dim doc As Document
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    Dim paras As Paragraphs
    Set paras = doc.Paragraphs
    Dim para As Paragraph
    Dim sents As Sentences
    Dim sent As Range
    For Each para In paras

        Set sents = para.Range.Sentences
        For Each sent In sents
            Debug.Print sent.Text
        Next

    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

if text is in other contains special character or is in another language the above code will not work this was the solution i came up with on one of task i performed

```
    Dim para As Paragraph
    Dim sentence() As String
    For Each para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
          sentence() = Split(para.Range.Text, Chr(11))
            For i = 0 To UBound(sentence)
                  Msgbox(sentence(i))
            next i
    next
```