# How to grammatically parse sentences using Microsoft Word Automation

Tags: c#, parsing, vba, ms-word, office-automation

I have written some code that parses sentences from a Microsoft Word document based on the suggestions found at the following URLs:

[Open Word document using C#](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5db48b80-59ec-44e7-afdd-04c53f4526fc/open-word-document-using-c)

[Using VBA to parse text in an MS Word document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756990/using-vba-to-parse-text-in-an-ms-word-document)

[How to Automate Microsoft Word using C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316384)

I wrote a small function that reads in a document and outputs its sentences via debug statements:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;


private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    oWord.Visible = true;

    object filename = textBox1.Text;

    oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open(filename, ref oMissing, true, false, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
        ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

    Sentences sentences;

    sentences = oDoc.Sentences;

    Debug.WriteLine("sentences=" + sentences.ToString());

    foreach (Range r in sentences)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("range.Text=" + r.Text);
    }
}
```

It does just about as good of a job as I have done previously using the `Mid` function on strings.  I was expecting it to do much better, considering MS Word has grammar check capabilities.  Is there some way to make use of MS Word's grammar abilities in order to get it to be smarter about sentence parsing?

Comment: Your title is a bit confusing.  Consider adding `grammar` to the title.

Comment: Okay, I modified my title as requested.

Comment: I've done a lot with Interop(tho mostly w/ Excel), and I've not seen any way to do exactly what you're asking.  Perhaps another edit might be to give an example of what you're trying to parse, in order to see how it doesnt work with your current code.  Perhaps there is a different way.

Comment: The Range objects returned by the Sentences object aren't smart enough to parse abbreviations.  Sometimes when I use exclamation marks and questions the range I get returned is blank, with the next Range object returned the subsequent sentence in the document.  I was just hoping Word would be smarter than this.

Comment: By the way, I was hoping for a quick and dirty solution using Word instead of having to make use of a "real" Natural Language Parser.  Otherwise, I'd just go back to my simple parsing and deal with it manually.